# unexpected end of file error when unzipping file node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zlib, fs

I am trying to unzip a text file using Zlib library in node.js, but i get unexpected end of file error, when piping the files’s Readstream content towards a Gunzip object, here is my snippet:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require("zlib");

var readable = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt');
var readableGz = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt.gz');
var writableGz = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/greet.txt.gz');
var gZip = zlib.createGzip();
var gUnZip = zlib.createGunzip();

readable.pipe(gZip).pipe(writableGz);   // compress file
readableGz.pipe(gUnZip).on("error", function(e){    // uncompress file
    console.log("error, " + e);
});
```

The greet.txt has some random text in it, and all the files used are already created in the directory, however an error event is triggered when the last line reaches

Comment: You are writing and reading in parallel. Wait until it's finished writing before reading.

Comment: if i first compress the file, and then comment that part, and just run the part when i try to uncompress it, the same error is still happening

Answer (score 6):

All `node` operations are asynchronous, so you have to listen for `finish` event.

```js
readable.pipe(gZip).pipe(writableGz)
   .on('finish', function () {  // finished
        console.log('Done. Now you can start reading.'); 
});
```

Here is a working code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const zlib = require("zlib");

var readable = fs.createReadStream('./greet.txt');
var writableGz = fs.createWriteStream('./greet.txt.gz');
var gZip = zlib.createGzip();
var gUnZip = zlib.createGunzip();

readable
    .pipe(gZip)
    .pipe(writableGz)
    .on('finish', function () {  // finished
        console.log('Done. Now you can start reading.');
        var readableGz = fs.createReadStream('./greet.txt.gz');
        readableGz
            .pipe(gUnZip)  // extract file
            .on("error", function (e) {
                console.log("error, " + e); 
            });
});
```

Comment: I tried this:     readable.pipe(gZip).pipe(writableGz); // compress file

    writableGz.end(function () { 
        console.log('Done. Here you can start reading.'); 
     readableGz.pipe(gUnZip).on("error", function(e){ // uncompress file
      console.log("error, " + e);
     });
});   but still not working

Comment: yes!, the .gz file gets emptied, but the same error is still being triggered

Comment: @PabloMarino Do you mean, that you copy-pasted my working code where I added `.on('finish',` and it shows you an error? If true - it means you broke something in your node setup. It passes with only `Done. Now you can start reading.` message in two setups where I tried.

Comment: Yeah, ALL node operations are async especially methods like `fs.writeFileSync` or `execSync`... Therefore we need different methods with appendix "sync" because everything is async... So, sorry, but shouldn't it say "because you're using async operattions only"